# servlet context

Tags: rest, servlets, spring-mvc

I have below web.xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>rest.service</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.abc</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <jsp-config>
  <taglib>
       <taglib-uri>wcm_rates</taglib-uri>
       <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/lib/wcm-rates.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
  </jsp-config>  
</web-app>
```

In Spring MVC servlet context I add some attributes. I am expecting that the attributes will be available in servlet context when any REST URL is invoked.

But to my surprise those attributes are not appearing when a REST Url is invoked.

I am adding attribute as `servletContext.setAttribute(xmlFile.getName(), map)`; and pulling as `request.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("test.xml");`

I have verified that I am using the same attribute name to store and pull.

Can somebody please help me so that I can share the attributes between Spring MVC and REST?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us some code: how you set attributes, and how you get them.

Comment: Edit your question. Don't post code in comments. I guess you're getting the attribute with a different name from the one used to set the attribute (i.e. the name of the file is probably not `"test.xml"`).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ServletContext Directly from the request , why do you get it from the session

**change from**

```
request.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("test.xml")
```

**to**

```
 request.getServletContext().getAttribute("test.xml")
```

Comment: there is no method "getServletContext" in HttpServletRequest.

Comment: Check java doc : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set/get the attributes from one of the following scopes:

1. request
2. session
3. application

If you are using `servletContext.setAttribute(xmlFile.getName(), map);`it means you are adding to the application scope. So to retrieve the attribute value, use `servletContext.getAttribute("test.xml");`

Check below link for more details,

https://www.studytonight.com/servlet/attribute.php